# XGBoost: is tuning max depth effectively the same as tuning min_child_weight, or vice versa?

Tags: boosting, hyperparameter

XGBoost allows the user to tune both parameters, max depth and min_child_weight. Since both hyperparameters control the depth of trees, it seems that you would only really need to tune one. However, all the blogs/tutorials I see online tune BOTH simultaneously, and I don't understand why.

Is there any reason to tune both?

Comment: Many more parameters of XGBoost reduce the tree size, and they all do it in a different way. In reality, you don't need to find optimal values for all these parameters simultaneously as they go hand-in-hand and different choices lead to comparable models.

Comment: @MichaelM But so, are you saying that there is no point in optimizing both, Max Depth and MCW, as they accomplish the same thing?